# 'At least one choice' Genetic Algorithm Constraint

Tags: r, constraints, mathematical-optimization, genetic-algorithm

I just started learning genetic algorithms in R using [this example](http://www.r-bloggers.com/genetic-algorithms-a-simple-r-example/) and I've run into an interesting problem trying to apply it.  I have a dataset of shops, supply centers, and distance (miles) between shops and supply centers in the data frame `dataset`:

```
Shop    Center    Distance  DistanceSave
A       1         700       300
A       2         200       800
A       3         300       700
B       1         400       600
B       2         100       900
B       3         150       850
C       1         600       400
C       2         500       500
C       3         200       800
```

I'm trying to minimize `Distance` (or maximize `DistanceSave` which is 1000 minus `Distance`) subject to the constraint that each shop must be tied to a `Center` and I'm having trouble coding that last part:

```
#Generate Evaluation Function
library(genalg)
evalFunc <- function(x) {
    current_solution_savings <- x %*% dataset$DistanceSave
    current_solution_shop <- length(unique(dataset$shop[x==1]))

    #Set Conditions in Function
    if (current_solution_shop != length(unique(dataset$Shop)))
        return(0) else return(-current_solution_savings)
}

#Run GA Algorithm with 100 iterations
iter = 100
GAmodel <- rbga.bin(size = genes, popSize = 200, iters = iter, mutationChance = 0.01, 
                    elitism = T, evalFunc = evalFunc)
cat(summary.rbga(GAmodel))
```

I thought the `current_solution_shop != length(unique(dataset$Shop))` condition would be enough but unfortunately it's not, sometimes it still assigns the same restaurant twice.

EDIT:  It looks like the [Facility Location Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facility_location_problem) is what I need to research, but can anyone recommend a multi-facility approach for R or Python?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to assign each shop to exactly one center and aren't allowed to assign multiple shops to a particular center then this is called the assignment problem, and can be solved exactly in an efficient manner using linear programming.

Here's an approach using the `lp.assign` function from the `lpSolve` package:

```
# Cost matrix (shops as rows, centers as columns)
(dist.mat <- matrix(dat$Distance, nrow=3))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]  700  400  600
# [2,]  200  100  500
# [3,]  300  150  200

# Solve the assignment problem
library(lpSolve)
sol <- lp.assign(dist.mat, "min")
sol$solution
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    0    1    0
# [2,]    1    0    0
# [3,]    0    0    1
sol$objval
# [1] 800
```

The optimal solution assigns store A to center 2, store B to center 1, and store C to center 3, with cost 800.

Comment: Thanks this is actually a very helpful!  What if I have less centers than shops and I'm okay with several shops going to the best center across all alternatives, would this still find the optimal mix after looking through all alternatives?

Comment: @gtnbz2nite then why not just assign each shop to the center with the shortest distance?

Comment: believe me I know that would be the most straightforward way lol but in the future I'd like to see if I had 1000 shops and given a set of say 50 centers, what if we could only go to 20?  Then the job would be to assign each restaurant to a center but ensure that you go to the best 20...it seemed Genetic Algorithms could help with that last constraint...so start small and go big you know?